# Capturing all data in non-whole train, test, and validate splits

Tags: python, split, sampling, training-data

just wondering if a better solution exists for this sort of problem.

We know that for a X/Y percentage split of an even number we can get an exact split of the data - for example for data size 10:

```
10 * .6 = 6
10 * .4 = 4
          10
```

Splitting data this way is easy, and we can guarantee we have all of the data and nothing is lost. However where I am struggling is on less friendly numbers - take 11

```
11 * .6 = 6.6
11 * .4 = 4.4
          11
```

However we can't index into an array at `i = 6.6` for example. So we have to decide how to to do this. If we take JUST the integer portion we lose 1 data point -

```
First set = 0..6
Second set = 6..10
```

This would be the same case if we floored the numbers.

However, if we take the ceiling of the numbers:

```
First set = 0..7
Second set = 7..12
```

And we've read past the end of our array.

This gets even worse when we throw in a 3rd or 4th split (30,30,20,20 for example).

Is there a standard splitting procedure for these kinds of problems? Is data loss accepted? It seems like data loss would be unacceptable for dependent data, such as time series.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** The values `.6` and `.4` are chosen by me. They could be any two numbers that sum to `1`.

Comment: @anonymous in the case of two splits, yes you could floor and take the rest as the second set. In a case where we have 3 splits, you cannot do that as easily.

Comment: In case of 3 split, take round value of two split and take the value of 3rd split as the value of len(my_list) - val_split_1 - val_split2 where len() gives the length of the list. Added the answer as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, notice that your problem is not limited to odd-sized arrays as you claim, but any-sized arrays. How would you make the 56%-44% split of a 10 element array? Or a 60%-40% split of a 4 element array?

There is no standard procedure. In many cases, programmers do not care that much about an exact split and they either do it by flooring or rounding one quantity (the size of the first set), while taking the complementary (array length - rounded size) for the other (the size of the second).

This might be ok in most cases when this is an one-off calculation and accuracy is not required. **You have to ask yourself what your requirements are**. For example: are you taking thousands of 10-sized arrays and each time you are splitting them 56%-44% doing some calculations and returning a result? You have to ask yourself what accuracy do you want. Do you care if your result ends up being 
the 60%-40% split or the 50%-50% split?

As another example imagine that you are doing a 4-way equal split of 25%-25%-25%-25%. If you have 10 elements and you apply the rounding technique you end up with 3,3,3,1 elements. Surely this will mess up your results.

If you do care about all these inaccuracies then the first step is consider whether you can to adjust either the array size and/or the split ratio(s).

If these are set in stone then the only way to have an accurate split of any ratios of any sized array is to **make it probabilistic**. You have to split multiple arrays for this to work (meaning you have to apply the same split ratio to same-sized arrays multiple times). The more arrays the better (or you can use the same array multiple times).

So imagine that you have to make a 56%-44% split of a 10 sized array. This means that you need to split it in 5.6 elements and 4.4 elements **on the average**.

There are many ways you can achieve a 5.6 element average. The easiest one (and the one with the smallest variance in the sequence of tries) is to have 60% of the time a set with 6 elements and 40% of the time a set that has 5 elements.

0.6*6 + 0.4*5 = 5.6

In terms of code this is what you can do to decide on the size of the set each time:

```
import random

array_size = 10
first_split = 0.56
avg_split_size = array_size * first_split 
floored_split_size = int(avg_split_size)

if avg_split_size > floored_split_size:
    if random.uniform(0,1) > avg_split_size - floored_split_size:
        this_split_size = floored_split_size
    else: 
        this_split_size = floored_split_size + 1    
else:
    this_split_size = avg_split_size
```

You could make the code more compact, I just made an outline here so you get the idea. I hope this helps.

Comment: Though I think anonymous's answer fits the problem domain I was looking for (whole number splits such as 60/40, 70/30 and constrained to 3 sets) I think your answer is more complete IN GENERAL and as a result I'll go ahead and award you the points. The probabilistic argument seems to be the more complete way to handle this problem when generalized.

Comment: To further expand on my point I think it would acceptable to have some loss in "completeness" if a user asks to split a 7 element set 4 ways, 25% each. I think this is implicit in the problem that you need to have _enough_ data to begin with. As such if you wanted to split 3 ways and have _enough_ data in each you'd want to consider that.

Comment: Thank you @rec. I am not sure what you mean by whole number split. In your question you do not place any limitation on the split ratios. And even if you did place limitations on the split ratios, since the length of the array can be anything, you will get non-integer splits. If a loss in accuracy is acceptable or not depends on your application's requirements, as I wrote in my answer. Finally, about having enough data: you do not need lots of a data, you can do the exact (i.e. average) split by using the same array multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ciel()` or `floor()` use [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) instead. For example:

```
>>> round(6.6)
7.0
```

The value returned will be of `float` type. For getting the integer value, type-cast it to `int` as:

```
>>> int(round(6.6))
7
```

This will be the value of your first *split*. For getting the second split, calculate it using `len(data) - split1_val`. This will be applicable in case of 2 split problem.

In case of *3 split*, take round value of two *split* and take the value of 3rd split as the value of `len(my_list) - val_split_1 - val_split2`

In a Generic way, **For N split**:

> Take the **`round()`** value of `N-1` split. And for the last value, do **`len(data)` - *"value of N round() values"***.

where `len()` gives the length of the list.

Comment: Take n = 15; 
Then .7*15 = 10.5, .3*15 = 4.5; but round(10.5) + round(4.5) = 11+5 = 16

Comment: It almost seems like you need to have a special case that if rounding goes over just use the data size instead (in this case 15). However, that seems sloppy and error prone.

Comment: Updated the answer. Basically For N split, you need to take the `round()` value of N-1 split. And for the last value, do `len(data)` - "N round values".

Answer (score 0):

Let's first consider just splitting the set into two pieces.

Let `n` be the number of elements we are splitting, and `p` and `q` be the proportions, so that

`p+q == 1`

I assert that the parts after the decimal point will always sum to either `1` or `0`, **so we should use `floor` on one and `ceil` on the other**, and we will always be right.

Here is a function that does that, along with a test. I left the print statements in but they are commented out.

```
def simpleSplitN(n, p, q):
    "split n into proportions p and q and return indices"
    np = math.ceil(n*p)
    nq = math.floor(n*q)
    #print n, sum([np, nq]) #np and nq are the proportions
    return [0, np] #these are the indices we would use

#test for simpleSplitN
for i in range(1, 10):
    p = i/10.0;
    q = 1-p
    simpleSplitN(37, p, q);
```

For the mathematically inclined, here is the proof that the decimal proportions will sum to `1`

`-----------------------`

We can express `p*n` as `n/(1/p)`, and so by the division algorithm we get integers `k` and `r`

`n == k*(1/p) + r` with `0 <= r < (1/p)`

Thus `r/(1/p) == p*r < 1`

We can do exactly the same for `q`, getting

`q*r < 1` (this is a different r)

It is important to note that `q*r` and `p*r` are the *part after the decimal* when we divide our `n`.

Now we can add them together (we've added subscripts now)

`0 <= p*(r_1) < 1
0 <= q*(r_2) < 1`

`=> 0 < p*r + q*r == p*n + q*n + k_1 + k_2 == n + k_1 + k_2 < 2`

But by closure of the integers, `n + k_1 + k_2` is an integer and so

`0 < n + k_1 + k_2 < 2`

means that `p*r + q*r` must be either `0` or `1`. It will only be `0` in the case that our `n` is divided evenly.

Otherwise we can now see that our fractional parts will always sum to `1`.

`-----------------------`

We can do a very similar (but slightly more complicated) proof for splitting `n` into an arbitrary number (say `N`) parts, but instead of them summing to `1`, they will sum to an integer less than `N`.

Here is the general function, it has uncommented print statements for verification purposes.

```
import math
import random

def splitN(n, c):
    """Compute indices that can be used to split
    a dataset of n items into a list of proportions c
    by first dividing them naively and then distributing
    the decimal parts of said division randomly
    """
    nc = [n*i for i in c];
    nr = [n*i - int(n*i) for i in c] #the decimal parts
    N = int(round(sum(nr)))          #sum of all decimal parts
    print N, nc
    for i in range(0, len(nc)):
        nc[i] = math.floor(nc[i])
    for i in range(N):                  #randomly distribute leftovers
        nc[random.randint(1, len(nc)) - 1] += 1
    print n,sum(nc);                    #nc now contains the proportions
    out = [0]                           #compute a cumulative sum
    for i in range(0, len(nc) - 1):
        out.append(out[-1] + nc[i])
    print out
    return out

#test for splitN with various proportions
c = [.1,.2,.3,.4]
c = [.2,.2,.2,.2,.2]
c = [.3, .2, .2, .3]
for n in range( 10, 40 ):
    print splitN(n, c)
```

If we have leftovers, we will never get an even split, so we distribute them randomly, like @Thanassis said. If you don't like the dependency on `random`, then you could just add them all at the beginning or at even intervals.

Both of my functions output indices but they compute proportions and thus could be slightly modified to output those instead per user preference.